# QtCombobox items with text and image button

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt. I have a QtCombobox and wanted to have (text1 notepad.icon) kind of items. So when I click on the notepad icon it will open up the file in notepad. How can I create such a combobox? Please guide. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By Using UI designer:**

1. Double click the existent combobox
   [image]
2. add new items and click "Properties" to add the icon[image]

**By hand-crafting:**

(suppose `QComboBox` "combox" has been instantiated)

```
combox.addItem(const QIcon & icon, const QString & text)
```

---

Please read Qt documents if you have any further trouble:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html